# Is there a way to unload fonts loaded via loadFontFromList in flutter desktop application?

Tags: flutter, custom-font, flutter-desktop

I'm making an application for **Flutter** **Desktop** and need to load and use the font files in the local directory.

The fonts were loaded through the **loadFontFromList** function.
But I couldn't find a way to unload the loaded font.
Is there any way to unload the fonts?

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution to unload the fonts?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like https://pub.dev/packages/font_face_observer (Font Face Observer package) has `unload`, which will likely do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way, I am making a native application, not a web. The link you sent seems to be a library related to fonts for the web.